# Unable to redirect Django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to build a simple blog with a basic post function through a very simple form. The function I am trying to accomplish is:

if the new post POSTs (no errors etc.) save to the database and redirect to the newly created post_details page. Otherwise I want it to re render the post form again. I keep getting the error NoReverseMatch at /post/pk and I cannot find my error. I am obviously not understanding something properly. The related code is below:

**views.py**

```
def post_new(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = PostForm()
return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**post_edit.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>New post</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my error inside my link for in my template view post_detail.html:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

It was redirecting properly to post_detail.html but the link above was breaking my page.